# API call is taking a lon time (Dataset 250.000 records)

Tags: javascript, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I make user of api calls to get the date to the frontend but my database table contains 250.000 rows.

And I user this query in my .NET Core application

```
IQueryable<Message> query = context.Message;
        query = query.Where((x) => x.Unit == unitId);
        return await query.ToListAsync();
```

And I use a HTTPGet request to get the answers with:

```
function getAllMessagesFromUnit (){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://localhost:44305/api/Units", true)
xhttp.send();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    var tbody = document.getElementById("apiTable").querySelector("tbody");
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    if(this.readyState == 4 & this.status == 200){
        JSON.parse(this.responseText).forEach(function(data, index){
           tbody.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + data.id + "</td>";
        });
    }
}
```

}

This returns 808 records, but it takes 4.7 seconds to load. How can I improve this performance?

I Use .NET CORE with Entity Framework for the backend and for the frontend javascript!

Answer (score 1):

If this is consistently an issue, then presumably you have either a very large table or very wide rows.

For the first problem, you can fix the performance by creating an index:

```
create index idx_table_unit on table(unit);
```

For the second, you can select only the columns you need.

Of course, there could be other issues, such as bandwidth issues between the database and the application, or contention on the server.